# Azure Active Directory Logout with ADAL library. Angular, TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, azure, azure-active-directory, adal

I have 2 open tabs in a browser. How to logout using adal from one tab, but be able to successfully use another one. In my case when you log out from one, there is no possibility to do anything from another tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is known limitation of the library in multiple tabs when you use localStorage. You should not have these issues if you set the cacheLocation to "sessionStorage" as session storage is not shared between multiple tabs.

Comment: Thanks, I will try

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. I am using session storage, but I am able to log in two different users in the same browser, which I don't want. Do you able to solve it?